# Прошу подсказать почему перебивает стиль?

Tags: scss, pug

Подскажите почему не работают св-ва. Вроде ни чего не должно перебивать.
1) "text-decoration: none;"
2)  &-action не применяется color

```css
.header {
    border: 1px solid red;
    &__up{
        list-style-type: none;
        display: flex;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
        margin: 10px 0;
        & a{
            color: #777777;
            font-family: Lato, sans-serif;
            font-size: 16px;
            font-weight: 300;
            line-height: 22px;
            text-decoration: none;
            margin-right: 40px;
            text-decoration: none;
            position: relative;
            &::before {
                content: ">";
                color: #e95924;
                display: block;
                position: absolute;
                top: -2px;
                left: -23px;
                font-size: 30px;
            }
        }
        &-action{
            color:red;
        } 
    }
    &__basket {
        border: 1px solid red;
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        right: 0;
        font-size: 50px;
        & i{
            padding: 20px 10px;
        }
    }
}
```

```html
doctype html
html
  head
    meta(charset='UTF-8')
    meta(name='viewport', content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0')
    link(href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:300,300i,400,400i,700,700i,900,900i" rel="stylesheet")
    link(rel='stylesheet', type='text/css', href='styles/style.css')
    link(rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css")
    link(rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous")
  body
    section.header
      .container
        .row
          .col
            ul.header__up
              li
                a.header__up-action(href="#") My Account
              li
                a(href="#") My Wishlist
              li 
                a(href="#") My Card 
              li 
                a(href="#") Checkout
              li 
                a(href="#") Log In
            .header__basket 
              a(href="#") 
                i.fa.fa-shopping-basket
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.header__up a` имеет приоритет над `.header__up-action`
Сделайте

```
.header {
    /***/
    &__up{
        /***/
        & a{
            /***/
            &.header__up-action {
                color: red;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Либо `!important`, либо задайте другой класс для `a.header__up-action`.

Comment: спасибо, !important решает всё

Comment: Я бы это сделал самым последним решением. А самым первым - задал бы иной класс для ссылки. `a.action` и описание для него в коде scss было бы красивым и правильным.